# how to return an error from the rpc server (StreamServerInterceptor) to the client

Tags: go, grpc

There is such a service:

```
service Recording {
    rpc Record(stream ReqData) returns(stream RespData) {}
}
```

Authentification is done on the server in StreamServerInterceptor and I need to get an authentification error on the client. Here is the code example, that i wrote on the server:

```golang
grpc.NewServer(grpc.StreamInterceptor(func(srv interface{}, ss grpc.ServerStream, info *grpc.StreamServerInfo, handler grpc.StreamHandler) error {
        return errors.New("test")
    }))
```

there is no error on the client when calling the `Record` service, but when I'm writing to stream I get the `io.EOF` error, how do I get the test error on the client?

PS
I also tried `status.Errorf(7, "test")` and it turned out the same.

Answer (score 0):

You will only get [StatusRuntimeException](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/StatusRuntimeException.html) in client side, which will contain [StatusCode](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/api/src/main/java/io/grpc/Status.java). Use proper status code (**UNAUTHENTICATED**) while building StatusRuntimeException at Server side and return it on ***.onError()***.

Comment: that's not the point. I have a stream in two directions, I expected an error on Send() it is not on Send(), it is on Recv()